# Does postgresql use bigger indexes when creating smaller indexes?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have an index on two columns

```
create index test1 on pointless (x,y);
```

And later I decide to create a partial index

```
create index test2 on pointless (x) where y > 0;
```

Does Postgres use index `test1` when creating index `test2` or does it re-scan the original table?

I'm just wondering as I'm sitting here waiting for some indexes to be created on a large table... thinking, that perhaps I should have created the largest index first.

Comment: What I know, it rescanning table - indexes are not used for creating other indexes.

Comment: Right, but your `CREATE INDEX` can be faster in v11, because it can use parallel table scan. Did you set `maintenance_work_mem` high to speed it up? BTW, don't create too many indexes!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is the word "Right" in your comment a reference to the preceding comment, or the original question?

Comment: @PavelStehule do you have some knowledge of the inner workings of pgsql or is that just an educated guess?

Comment: My "right" is the former, and Pavel is an experienced PostgreSQL hacker.

Comment: @AlexR - I am not a specialist on indexes - but I hope, so I know some about Postgres - and I did fast check of source code. It was a fast check only, so I can be wrong, but it looks so DDL commands use direct scan of relation, and didn't use a SELECT. Then there is very low possibility to use other indexes for this case.

Comment: Thanks @PavelStehule. I think you should post that as the answer.